# awk to count lines (reads) in a column

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I have a file in which I have reads associated in the last columns  associated with a gene.

```
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:21577:2860    44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:12188:3487    44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:9524:3758 44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:7243:4130 44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:20035:10131   44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:14291:16898   44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11101:10796:17822   44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11102:17796:2683    44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11103:22603:1930    44  +
chr7    2457938 2457981 Naca    +   chr7    2457938 2457981 NS500455:81:HTVKJBGXC:1:11103:2286:7789 44  +
```

`chr7 2457938 2457981 Naca + chr7 2457938 2457981 44  + number of reads` i.e. number of times columns 6-8 occur. Here in this example they coccur 10 times. I want this written as a separate column.

I tried doing this with awk `awk '!seen[$5]++' | awk '{a[$12]=1;} END{for (k in a)n++; print n;}'` but it does not work.
Can someone help.
regards,
Amit.

Comment: What is the logic for the output?

Comment: Along with what Raman asked above, just want to ask here you are using `awk '!seen[$5]++' ` command does that mean you are removing duplicates on 5th column? Kindly confirm on same once too, because your shown samples should be more clear if this is the case, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The logic of output is to count the number of times the 12-15th column occur associated with each gene.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 How else to show that for 1 gene n number of reads (12-15th) column are associated. Am still learning awk. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]++
  next
}
($1 in arr){
  print $0,arr[$1]
  delete arr[$1]
}
' Input_file Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case your samples are in sorted form by 1st column try following then:

```
awk '
prev!=$1 && prev{
  print prevLine,count
}
{
  prev=$1
  prevLine=$0
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print prevLine,count
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** If records are not sorted by 1st column then use `sort` command with Input_file and pass its output to 2nd solution too.